# update value of Key in key value pair

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq statement that returns a list of `<string,string>` key value pairs. The problem is that all the values in the key need to be replaced. Is there a way to do a replace in the select of the linq without having to iterate through the entire list?

```
var pagesWithControl = from page in sitefinityPageDictionary
                       from control in cmsManager.GetPage(page.Value).Controls
                       where control.TypeName == controlType
                       select page; // replace "~" with "localhost"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the key, but you can return a new object with the new key:

```
 var pagesWithControl = from page in sitefinityPageDictionary
                   from control in cmsManager.GetPage(page.Value).Controls
                   where control.TypeName == controlType
                   select new 
                           { 
                             Key = page.Key.Replace("~",localhost"), 
                             page.Value 
                           };
```

or if it has to be a KeyValuePair:

```
var pagesWithControl =  
   from page in sitefinityPageDictionary
   from control in cmsManager.GetPage(page.Value).Controls
   where control.TypeName == controlType
   select 
   new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(page.Key.Replace("~",localhost"), page.Value);
```

Comment: Now imagine that you use a KeyValuePair together with the params keyword on the method signature and wanted to change the value of one of the passed KeyValuePair.

Comment: Continuing: "That change would be replicated to the method caller."